# Grouping a dataset into time intervals then counting many columns within each period

Tags: r, plyr

My data set comes from a process control system with various digital inputs created by logical switching functions (recorded as 'alarms').  Each event changes the state of the input from 0 to 1 which is recorded as a "N" or "Y" character in the dataset, thus:

```
tstamp             alarm0   alarm1  alarm2  alarm3  alarm4...alarm204
2015-10-01 16:23:06 N       N       N       N       N
2015-10-01 16:23:36 N       N       N       N       N
2015-10-01 16:24:06 Y       Y       N       Y       N
2015-10-01 16:24:36 Y       N       N       Y       N
2015-10-01 16:25:06 N       Y       N       Y       N
2015-10-01 16:25:36 N       N       N       N       N
```

...etc, producing ~1m rows per year.

My first aim is to count the number of "Y" within a given period (say hourly or daily) and to compare that with the frequency of events from other similar periods using a heatmap or similar.   My second aim is to identify the number of times an alarm switches from 0 to 1, ie to determine if an event occurs infrequently and persists for a long period or if it occurs frequently for a short period.

I've cut the dataset into suitable time periods using...

```
cut(Mydf$tstamp,breaks="hour")
```

and I'm able to count "Y"s in the entire dataset using...

```
apply(X=Mydf,2,FUN = function(x) length(which(x=="Y")))
```

I've been unable to cut and count the the dataset when grouped by tstamp where breaks = 'hour' or 'week' or 'month'.

I've been trying to use ddply {plyr} to cut the dataset into time periods then count the instances of "Y" within each time period however this has been unsuccessful.

Here's my sample .csv dataset 1000 rows x 80 cols (~ 175kb)... 
    http://1drv.ms/1HsdY75

```
library(plyr)

# Read in the data files...
Mydf <- read.csv("C:/.../Mydf_small.csv")

# convert tstamp from "factor" class to "POSIXct" class (requires plyr      package)
Mydf$tstamp <- as.POSIXct(Mydf$tstamp) # turn tstamp into a time format that can be evaluated
Mydf$timebrk <- cut(Mydf$tstamp,breaks="hour") # set the time interval to  count the number of active alarms in
mylevels <- unique(Mydf$timebrk) 

# example... this counts all instances of "Y" regaldless of mylevel...
MyCount <- apply(X=Mydf,2,FUN = function(x) length(which(x=="Y")))
MyCount

# want to count instances of "Y" within mylevel (...but this doesn't work)
ddcount <- ddply(.data=Mydf,.variables=mylevels,.fun = function(x) length(which(x=="Y")))
ddcount
```

Any assistance on these matters appreciated...

Comment: Don't use levels, use the variable you want to split by (here 'timebrk')

Comment: Hi @Heroka.  Whether I use the variable 'mylevels' or the column name 'timebrk' I get the following error message.           > ddcount <- ddply(.data=Mydf,.variables=Mydf$timebrk,.fun = function(x) length(which(x=="Y")))
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:12: unexpected numeric constant
1: 2015-10-01 16
               ^ .      This implies to me that the value in 'timebrk' is supposed ot be of a specific format however the class is 'factor'.  I've also tried cut(... break="day") and get errors. I've also tried manually adding cut(.....,label=1:9 ) but still I am unable to get a result.

Comment: Try `ddcount <- ddply(data=Mydf,.(timebrk), fun=......? ` And please don't link to data, links can break and people are not likely to download them to their own machines.

Comment: Hi @Heroka, I've found a solution that works for me, I've had to replace the class of 'tstamp' from 'POSIXct' to 'chr'.  It appears that  the 'ddply' function wasn't handling the class of this field appropriately.
simply 'Mydf$tstamp <- as.character(Mydf$tstamp)'. fixed the issue.  Thank you for your assistance.